# PIVOT two columns into multiple rows

Tags: sql, pivot

**Source Table**

```
Subject_Name   Semester
------------------------
A1               1
B1               2
C1               3
D1               1
E1               2
```

**Desired Output**

```
1    2   3
---------------
A1  B1   C1
D1  E1
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT subject_name, 
                semester, 
                Row_number() OVER (partition BY semester ORDER BY subject_name DESC) AS Rn 
         FROM   sourcetable) 
SELECT [1], 
       [2], 
       [3] 
FROM   cte 
       PIVOT (Max(subject_name) 
             FOR semester IN ([1],[2],[3])) pvt
```

**Or:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT subject_name, 
               semester, 
               Row_number() OVER(partition BY semester ORDER BY subject_name DESC) AS Rn 
        FROM   sourcetable) src 
        PIVOT ( Max(subject_name) 
             FOR semester IN ([1],[2],[3]) ) piv
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a452/14)

**Output**:

```
1   2    3
A1  B1   C1
D1  E1   null
```